# Autofixture freeze indirect dependency

Tags: c#, unit-testing, xunit, nsubstitute, autofixture

Using `xunit`, `Autofixture` and `NSubstitute`

I have a class `MyClass` depends on `IServiceB` which in turn depends on `IServiceA` like below

```
    public interface IServiceA {
        string MethodInA();
    }

    public interface IServiceB {
        string MethodInB();
    }

    public class ServiceB : IServiceB {
        private readonly IServiceA _a;
        public ServiceB(IServiceA a) {
            _a = a;
        }
        public string MethodInB() {
            return _a.MethodInA();
        }
    }

    public class MyClass {
        private readonly IServiceB _b;
        public MyClass(IServiceB b) {
            _b = b;
        }
        public string MyMethod() {
            return _b.MethodInB();
        }
    }
```

Then I have below `xunit` test

```
      [Fact()]
        public void Test() {
            var _fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization { ConfigureMembers = true });
            var a = _fixture.Freeze<IServiceA>();
            a.MethodInA().Returns("Hello");
            var sut = _fixture.Create<MyClass>();
            Assert.Equal("Hello", sut.MyMethod());
        }
```

It will fail.

Why? Isn't it that if `MethodA()` is `frozen` to `Return("Hello")` then `MyMethod()` will always return `Hello`, right?

How do I make it pass without having to manually type out all the *intermediate* dependencies such as `IServiceB`?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure you can. Once you install the AutoNSubstituteCustomization, the concrete types are proxies that implement your interface, but aren't aware of the dependencies that your concrete implementations have.

I had to inject an instance of `ServiceB` with its dependent `IServiceA` to get this test to pass, which is the manual 'wiring' you're trying to avoid.

```
var _fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoNSubstituteCustomization() { ConfigureMembers = true });

var a = _fixture.Freeze<IServiceA>();
a.MethodInA().Returns("Hello");

// Appears that you have to do this to avoid NSubstitute registering a proxy of IServiceB
_fixture.Inject(new ServiceB(a) as IServiceB);

var sut = _fixture.Create<MyClass>();

Assert.Equal("Hello", sut.MyMethod());
```

It seems like there should be, and could be that I don't know about, a way of telling the `AutoNSubstituteCustomization` to opt-out of substituting certain types, but then that defeats the 'auto' element of that customisation.

Comment: I see. If it is not possible to do so. Then when unit test and if we have to freeze an very distant service,  then it becomes quite tedious to have to specify all the intermediate dependencies. For example, ```IServiceA``` could be a settings' repo to retrieve some timezone info, and concrete class ```ServiceB``` could be a concrete class prepare some holiday data. Then I want to test ```MyMethod``` under certain timezone. Quite tedious if the chain is long.